# Compare portfolio returns across time dimension

Tags: time-series, statistics, regression

I've designed a trading strategy and would like to understand whether the return profile for it differs for the trades implemented before and after the Covid pandemic. Specifically I would like to compare the return on investment and the number of trades opened in the two regimes. Also, the regime pre-covid is two/three time as long as the post-covid regime, so I will need to adjust for this.

Since I'm not comparing different strategies across the same dimension, but rather the same strategy across different time dimensions, I can't just run a simple OLS regression.

Any suggestions on what tests I could apply?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to regres with OLS? What's your dependend/indepent variables?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a test of differences in mean (return, number of trades...etc)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: For a start, did you run a simple (covid-1year to covid) vs (Covid t0 covid +1 year) to simply check actual returns and number of trades (before trying to do anything fancy)?